# Cannot get samples to run

Tags: eclipse, playn

I cannot launch the sample projects (cute and showcase) and do not know why.  I am developing in Eclipse, and therefore have followed the instructions in GettingStarted.

I have the following warning in Eclipse:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Classpath entry com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.    playn-cute-html     P/playn-cute-html   Classpath Dependency Validator Message
```

I don't know if this is the problem?  How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to upvote this question as I'm running into this same problem. But I don't have enough karma. So I'll offer a few of my own details here in the hope that someone can solve this.

My system:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Eclipse 3.7
- GWT SDK 2.4.0

I was able to get the showcase example running in Chrome when I ran the debug version in development mode with the GWT Chrome plugin. And I even got it running in non-development mode once -- but I'm not sure how! I was fiddling with various things.

I see this path is set in playn-samples/showcase/html/.classpath. Currently I have the following setting:

`<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER/com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.3.7.update.site_2.5.1"/>`

Based on some settings I ran into while Googling this problem, I changed it to:

`<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER/GWT"/>`

And that's when I got it running. But the setting doesn't seem to stick when I restart Eclipse and I haven't been able to recreate my success.

I suspect it's some sort of config setting but I'm just groping in the dark.

Comment: I just have:  
`<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER"/>`  
  
And I get this error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I myself haven't use much of Eclipse with playn, but I can tell you, you're not the first person running into these kind of problems with Eclipse and playn, I would strongly suggest you to do as much as you can via maven, as detailed in the Getting Started page http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted you can run and build via maven, and still use Eclipse for writting code. I hope this helps you.